# Excel Row Number with duplicated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, worksheet-function, row-number

I have to workbooks (1 sheet each) that I am comparing.

Example of Sheet 1:

```
PO     Line  AMT
PO1234  1    $5.00 
PO1234  2    $7.00 
PO5678  1    $10.00 
PO5678  2    $25.00
```

Example of Sheet 2:

```
PO      Line AMT
PO1234  1    $5.00 
PO1234  2    $7.00 
PO5678  1    $10.00 
PO5678  2    $25.00
```

I have tried match, and row formulas but only returns the row for the first match.

What I am looking for is row a formula that validates all 3 criteria and returns the valid row number like the attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following formula not using **Enter**, but instead, **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**
`=MATCH(1,(A2=Sheet2!A:A)*(B2=Sheet2!B:B)*(C2=Sheet2!C:C),0)`

[image]